# Useful resources for learning Spanish grammar at home?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, recursos

I've recently begun learning Spanish, and while I'm gaining a good understanding of vocabulary, I can't seem to find many effective resources for studying the grammar, without having to pay a lot of money. As a student, I don't have money to spend on textbooks so I would really appreciate your help! I have been using Lingodeer, which has quite useful grammar notes, but it also seems to go somewhat slowly.

Edit: I know I've come back to this post quite late, so apologies for that. To add some well-needed detail which will hopefully help, I am specifically looking for a website, app, podcast etc. with a linear curriculum of the basics of Spanish grammar.

For comparison, I am also learning Korean, using the websites https://howtostudykorean.com and https://talktomeinkorean.com, both of which offer well-organised curriculums for learning Korean grammar.

I would like a similar resource for learning Spanish grammar, if possible. However, if none come to mind, it would also be quite useful if someone could provide any kind of curriculum with a general idea of what order I should be learning certain grammar components in. This does not necessarily have to include grammar/vocabulary notes itself as I am okay with searching for those and/or making them myself. At the very least, I would just like a simple list of things I should learn in order to gain a strong foundation.

Thank you all! I hope the added detail helps at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100281/discussion-on-question-by-hafsah-h-useful-resources-for-learning-spanish-grammar).

Answer (score 2):

> This is a Community Wiki answer meant to have all the proposed resources in one single place. Please feel free to [edit](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/31842/edit) it to include any resources you think would fit the question.

#### Paid (but not expensive) courses

- Instituto Cervantes offers [paid online Spanish courses](https://ave.cervantes.es/en/content/what-ave-global) for any of the CEFR levels (A1, B2, etc.). The price varies depending on whether you pick a course with or without tutoring. The A1 course without tutoring costs 75€ which may or may not be expensive depending on your situation.

#### Free courses

- ...